# "caused by java.lang.reflect.invocationtargetexception" Getting error during android signed build generation

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio, mobile-application

I have a react native app, currently, I am trying to generate an android signed apk, but suddenly it's starting to give me an error.

RN Version : 0.63.0
typescript : 3.9.6.
Android version : 2020.3.1 Patch 2 ( Android studio arctic fox ).
JDK version : jdk-11.0.14

Earlier it was working fine, tried many solutions given based on the subject lines quoted part. But none of them are working.

Please let me know if you know anything about it.

[image]

Comment: Please share some more info, like screenshots or the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app level -> build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

This works for me